# Outlook VBA - Automatically create a folder based on date

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have created a VBA script that will automatically save pdf attachments. Does anyone here know how can I save the attachment based on the date? For Example, today is 02-04-2020 then this specific user emailed me with an pdf attachment then automatically a folder will be created with the name 02-04-2020 and all mail for that day will be stored in that folder. Then on next day another folder will be created. I really need to separate the incoming attachments by date.

Here is what I have so far

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim dateFormat
dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm")
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim getsender As String
saveFolder = "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Attachments\"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          If InStr(objAtt.FileName, ".pdf") > 0 Then
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
          End If
     Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone in codeproject.com help me solved my problem and I would like to acknowledge that person who has @CHill60 username. Thank you so much for helping me. Below code is from that person and that code solved my problem.

Here is a link of my posted question in codeproject.com
[https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5258321/Outlook-VBA-automatically-create-a-folder-based-on][1]

Here is the complete code @CHill60 posted. Hope this might be helpful to others.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim dateFormat As String
    dateFormat = Format(itm.CreationTime, "mm-dd-yyyy")

    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim getsender As String

    saveFolder = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\DLFolder\" & dateFormat & "\"

    CreateFolderIfNotExists saveFolder

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        If InStr(objAtt.FileName, ".pdf") > 0 Then
            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & objAtt.DisplayName
        End If

     Next
End Sub


Public Sub CreateFolderIfNotExists(folderName As String)
    Dim fs As Object
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Not fs.folderexists(folderName) Then
        fs.createfolder (folderName)
    End If
End Sub
```